Email QuickAction Not working correctly when being called from AURA
I am trying to build a lightning component that will pass the email addresses into to field of salesforce standard Email Quick Action.
Here is the component controller that I am using. This is correctly invoking the Email Quick Action on the Case Record Page, but somehow not passing the values of ToAddress and Body into the quick action. I followed this article from the quick action api developer guide to achieve this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/quickaction_api_setActionFieldValues.htm
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/case_feed_dev_guide.pdf

Has anyone ever built this scenario ever?
({
        sendEmailAction : function( cmp, event, helper) {
                var actionAPI = cmp.find("quickActionAPI");
                var targetField = { ToAddress: {value: "to@to.com"}, 
                                    TextBody: {value: "the text body", insertType: "replace"}
                                }
                var args = {actionName: "Case.SendEmail", recordId:cmp.get('v.recordId'), targetFields : targetField};
                actionAPI.setActionFieldValues(args).then(function(result){

                }).catch(function(error){
                        if(e.errors) {
                            console.log('test error', error);
                        }
                });
        }
})

